# Select features that share the same value in a certain column but also have different values in a different column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I have a dataset of plants, they are many different plant species that are given a numerical code in a column in the attribute table, but they are located in different land types which was also identified in another column , I want to make a selection that highlights the plant (or points) that share the same species ID but are located in different land types. Here is an example:

[image]

I want to know if there is a tool that I can use to select the points with OID 2, 3, 7, 8, and 9 since they are grouped by plant species but there is at least one point (i.e. plant) located in different land Types than all the other points that share the same Species ID. I am using ArcMap 10.2.1.

Quick note: there is no map or layer for the Land Type field.

Comment: Use the summary stats tool, case field is species & land type, but count on land type. This will identify the species of interest. Then look at help file about relating tables.

Comment: If you also want to investigate ArcPy/Python then your question will need a code attempt to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Convert land type to integers

[image]

Join it to original and populate new field (integer).

[image]

Apply summary statistics:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(in_table="Area_Units", out_table="in_memory/abc", statistics_fields="LU STD", case_field="SPECIE")
```

Output with summary table joined to original:

[image]

Your records are those where STD_LU > 0